# What is this the name of this Java state-based design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

At my work, we have surveys, and one survey involves multiple steps. I work in automation, so I design tests around the page-objects we create for these surveys. We call this particular survey a "flow" survey because it has multiple steps. So you can skip step1 (survey A), then complete or skip step 2 (survey B), then complete or skip step 3 (survey C). Naively, we could write a test that just has methods that look like this:

```
public void completeSurveyA() {
    //...
}
public void skipSurveyB() {
    //...
}
public void completeSurveyB() {
    //...
}
public void skipSurveyC() { 
    //...
}
public void completeSurveyC() {
    //...
}
```

You would use it like this

```
completeSurveyA();
skipSurveyB();
completeSurveyC();
```

However, that could be a problem because we might call `completeSurveyB()` before we call `completeSurveyA()`, call `completeSurveyA` twice, etc. and the test would break. To avoid this, I introduced a different approach where calling a method on surveyA would return a surveyB object, which would return a surveyC object.

```
public class SurveyFlow() {
    public SurveyB completeSurveyA() {
        //...
        return new SurveyB();
    }
    private class SurveyB() {
        public SurveyC skipSurveyB() {
            //...
            return new SurveyC();
        }
        public SurveyC completeSurveyB() {
            //...
            return new SurveyC();
        }
        private class SurveyC() {
            public void skipSurveyC() {
                //...
            }
            public void completeSurveyC() {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would use it like this

```
new SurveyFlow().completeSurveyA().skipSurveryB().completeSurveyC();
```

The pattern reminds me of a state machine because only certain methods are available to you in different states, but I'm wondering if there is a more specific name for this pattern.

Comment: Sounds like the State pattern to me.

Comment: Cross between a state machine and a fluent interface. Effluence?!

Comment: This seems like a special case of a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java).

Comment: Can you skip a step and  return to it later? Similariliy, can you complete a step but later regret the answers and revise it?

Comment: @forty-two No, you can only move forwards in the flow survey

Comment: Then it's a Sequence, isn't it?

Comment: @forty-two It's a sequence, yeah. However, I just realized that you can go backwards, so I will need to adjust my implementation slightly.

Comment: When the concept is clear i'm sure you'll find a proper name for it. If there is an existing pattern, that's fine but not really that intersting. Remember, there's only two difficult things in Computer Science: Naming things, cache invalidation and off by one one errors ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the classes of your example, it's a [FluentInterface](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html):

> Probably the most important thing to notice about this style is that the intent is to do something along the lines of an internal DomainSpecificLanguage. (...) The API is primarily designed to be readable and to flow.

It's not the builder pattern, because you're not building anything (i.e. you don't have a final `build()` method where data gathered in previous steps is used to create an instance).

It's not the state pattern either, because operations (`skip()` and `complete()` in this case) do not depend on the state of an object (actually steps don't have a state).

It *would have been* the state pattern if the whole survey had been modeled as an object with one method whose implementation depended on different states (in this case, the states would be the steps plus the action taken, i.e. `surveyACompleted`, `surveyASkipped`, `surveyBCompleted`, `surveyBSkipped`, etc, while the method would be something like `nextStep()`):

```
public class SurveyFlow {

    private SurveyState state; // this represents the current step

    public SurveyFlow(boolean skipFirst) {
        this.state = skipFirst ? new SurveyASkipped() : new SurveyACompleted();
    }

    void setState(SurveyState state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public void takeStep(boolean skipNext) { // takeStep operation delegated 
                                             // to the state (current step)
        this.state.takeStep(skipNext, this); // "this" passed to the step so 
                                             // that it can switch to the 
                                             // next step if needed
    }
}
```

The state would be polymorphically represented by each step of the `SurveyFlow`:

```
abstract class SurveyState {

    protected abstract void takeStep(boolean skipNext, SurveyFlow survey);
}
```

Survey A states would be as follows:

```
class SurveyACompleted extends SurveyState {

    protected void takeStep(boolean skipNext, SurveyFlow survey) {
        // ...

        survey.setState(skipNext ? new SurveyBSkipped() : new SurveyBCompleted());
    }
}

class SurveyASkipped extends SurveyState {

    protected void takeStep(boolean skipNext, SurveyFlow survey) {
        // ...

        survey.setState(skipNext ? new SurveyBSkipped() : new SurveyBCompleted());
    }
}
```

Survey B states would be as follows:

```
class SurveyBCompleted extends SurveyState {

    protected void takeStep(boolean skipNext, SurveyFlow survey) {
        // ...

        survey.setState(skipNext ? new SurveyCSkipped() : new SurveyCCompleted());
    }
}

class SurveyBSkipped extends SurveyState {

    protected void takeStep(boolean skipNext, SurveyFlow survey) {
        // ...

        survey.setState(skipNext ? new SurveyCSkipped() : new SurveyCCompleted());
    }
}
```

For your example:

1. Complete Survey A
2. Skip Survey B
3. Complete Survey C

You could do:

```
SurveyFlow survey = new SurveyFlow(false); // will complete survey A
survey.takeStep(true);                     // completed survey A and will skip survey B
survey.takeStep(false);                    // skipped survey A and will complete survey C
survey.takeStep(true);                     // completed survey C
```

If survey C is the last step, then it can ignore the `boolean` argument and shouldn't set further steps.

Comment: What do you mean by "As you're showing your classes now"?

Comment: Your example of the more state-pattern-esque approach was my initial approach, but I wanted something that was more descriptive--people don't know what step they're on when they call `takeStep` unless they're aware of the implementation of each step.

Comment: @michaelsnowden "I wanted something more descriptive" => it's a fluent interface. I totally agree that a fluent interface is much more descriptive and clear than a classical state pattern approach. Besides, it's less verbose.

Answer (score 1):

This is in a way the State pattern, but does not completely adhere to the State pattern described by GoF, because you are not changing the state of a single object, but rather creating and returning a new object of different class which you use afterwards.

Actually, this resembles much more the Builder pattern, where the `completeSurveyC()` acts as a `build` or `getResult` method to build a `Surway` from multiple consisting pieces specified earlier.

Comment: A builder is a specific type of fluent interface, specifically used to build something.